# What is "I introduce you to Mark" in Spanish?

Tags: gramática

I've just began to learn Spanish, and got a few questions.
When I want to say "I introduce you to Mark", is it okay to say " Te presento a Mark"and "Presentarte a Mark"?

I learned only "introduce (name) to (personal pronoun)" in my book, which is for example "Me presentas a Mark"(You introduce Mark to me). But I thought that sentence could also be translated as (You introduce me to Mark).

I want to know what is correct, or what is more proper or usual!

Thank you.

Comment: I introduce you to Mark is incorrect in English. We say: Let me introduce you to Mark. Otherwise, you are introducing him to us more than once. The simple present is only for a repetitive action or general statement: I study French at school.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are correct, but used in different ways.

Let's say that you (Sarah) and a friend (Mark) are walking together. You find another friend, let's call it Frank.

If you say: "Frank, **te presento a Mark**", you're telling Frank that your friend is called Mark. We could translate it as: "Frank, **I'm introducing you to Mark**".

But there's another way to tell it. You could say: "Frank, permíteme **presentarte a Mark**". We could translate this as: "Frank, let me **introduce you to Mark**". It's a more "polite" way to tell the same.

So, both are correct, but used in different sentences. They mean the same, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your original example is indeed ambiguous, and it could be interpreted either way in English. If you think about the intent though --that you and Mark be introduced-- then the ambiguity is not important. However there are ways to disambiguate.

*Presentar* means "to introduce", and it is a transitive verb, meaning that there is always a *[someone]* that goes with it, much like in English (to introduce *[someone]*).

In Spanish, *[someone]* can be replaced by *lo/la*; but if the a person is named, their name is preceded by *a*.

> *I introduce [John] - I introduce [him] =
> Yo presento [a Juan] - Yo [lo] presento*

The person to whom the *[someone]* is being introduced is the indirect object. This person can be replaced by the pronoun *le* (or *se* if paired with *lo/la*). It is necesary that their name also be preceded by *a*.

Confusion can arrise as an English speaker because the order of the sentence dictates who is introduced to whom.

> *I introduce Juan to Marcos // I introduce Marcos to Juan*

But in Spanish, it is not to straightforrward. The order doesn't matter as much as the function of the words in the sentence.

> *Yo presento a Juan a Marcos* = I introduce John to Mark

> *A Juan lo presento a Marcos* = I introduce John to Mark

> *A Marcos le presento a Juan* = I introduce John to Mark

En fin, the important thing to remember is that the person being introduced can be replaced by *lo/la* and the person to whom someone is being introduced can by replaced by *le (se)*. This tells us who is doing what in the sentence.

> *Me lo presentas* = You introduce him to me

> *Me le presentas* = You introduce me to him

Comment: The English is wrong. We never say; I introduce you to x. We say: Allow me or let me introduce you do x or I will now introduce you to Mark.  Otherwise, it's a repeated thing and introducing someone to someone only happens once.

Comment: I kept it simple for the sake of demonstrating the Spanish grammar on more of a 1:1 basis.

Comment: If presentar is transitive, you then would not say: Presenter a Juan a Marco. Presento Juan a Marco.

Comment: If presentar is transitive, it does not take a. You had no intention of writing a natural sentence?? In Spanish? She does not understand the grammar or she wouldn't have written that. It is not natural in English.

Comment: Incorrect. Since both are proper names, both are introduced with *a*. Del DPD: "Pero si el complemento directo es un nombre propio, es forzoso el uso de la preposición: Presentó a Juan a sus padres."

Comment: No, {yo] Presento Marco a Juan. There are not two preposition a's. My husband has confirmed this to me, he's from Spain.

Comment: Then he will know what the RAE is, and the Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas is one of their publications. My information is from here: https://www.rae.es/dpd/a

Comment: Why don't you ask the Spanish speakers here? That specific link to the dictionary does not contain this. The RAE: Transitive verb: 10. tr. Dar el nombre de una persona a otra en presencia de ambas para que se conozcan. Transitive verbs do not take "a". In any case, it is very awkward; Presento a Juan a Marco.

Comment: QUOTE, section 1.2.d) "Cuando el complemento directo de persona precedido de preposición coincide en la oración con otro complemento que también la lleva (por ejemplo, un complemento indirecto), puede omitirse la que antecede al complemento directo, para evitar confusiones: Presentó (a) su novio a sus padres. **Pero si el complemento directo es un nombre propio, es forzoso el uso de la preposición: Presentó a Juan a sus padres.**" Anyway, speak however you want. I will follow what the RAE says, explicitly.

Comment: The RAE says: Presentó su novio a sus padres. The RAE says complemento directo es un nombre proprio. It does not say **dos nombres proprios**...which is awkward. Ask the Spanish speakers here.

Comment: *Complemento directo* means the object of a transitive verb, those which you claim never take *a* before them. But as I said, it is your choice not to follow what is laid out by the governing body of the Spanish language. I am not going to argue since I have already given a source for my information. I have nothing else to say. :)